# How to calculate a date in Google Documents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I can calculate a date countdown pretty easily in sheets with a formula like this:

```
=MINUS(DATE(2015,5,25),TODAY())
```

Is there any way to add a date countdown in a Google Document?

If not,  how about copying calculated data from a cell in sheets to a Google document?

Comment: Hey JJ and welcome to Web Applications. I saw your post already on the Google+ community and thus removed the hash-tags !! Stick-a-round as it might take a bit.

Comment: Side remark: in a spreadsheet I would use [`DATEDIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055612?hl=en) which offers more flexibility in formatting. Concerning your question: should be possible with a script that runs every day, grabs values from the spreadsheet and inserts into the document. I'll look into it later.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a way to make a calculated date field, or link to a single Sheets field, so this is my closest solution for you.

Huge reference props to Ryan Heitner's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585272/insert-date-time-in-google-document

I've modified it to create a menu in your Google doc with one item to insert a string containing the # of full days left, with a description following it "X full days left!"

To set it up, in a google doc, go to Tools -> Script editor (if you don't have scripts already, you'll get a div, otherwise you get taken to a new tab asking which script to edit, or create a new one) and create a new blank project.

Put the below script in and save it whatever name you want.  Then refresh or load your google doc and you should have the new menu item.

*NOTE: This script is actually set for an end date of May 31, 2015 (var dtEnd = new Date(2015, 4, 31);) rather than the date you had. Adjust as needed, but remember the month is -1 of the actual month number since they're 0-based in this javascript-based scripting.*

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  // Or FormApp or SpreadsheetApp.
  ui.createMenu('DateCountdown')
      .addItem('Insert Date Countdown', 'insertDateCountdown')
      .addToUi();

}

function insertDateCountdown() {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  if (cursor) {
      // Attempt to insert text at the cursor position. If insertion returns null,
      // then the cursor's containing element doesn't allow text insertions.
      var d = new Date();
      var dtEnd = new Date(2015, 4, 31); //ADJUST MONTH by 1; month is 0-based!!
      // The Times are in milliseconds, and 86,400,000 is ms in a day
      var dayCount = Math.floor((dtEnd.getTime() - d.getTime()) / 86400000);
      var element = cursor.insertText(dayCount + " full days left!");
      if (element) {
        element.setBold(true);
      } else {
        DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text at this cursor location.');
      }
    } else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
  }

}
function pad (str, max) {
  str = str.toString();
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}
```

The script editor option:
[image]

The new menu item:
[image]

Comment: You could set a daily time trigger to run a script that updates the doc. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers